# Google Documents API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am using Google documents api.

```
DocsService service = new DocsService(APP_NAME);
service.query(qry, DocumentListFeed.class);
List<DocumentListEntry> docEntries = docFeed.getEntries();
for(DocumentListEntry entry : docEntries)
{
   System.out.println(entry.getQuotaBytesUsed());
}
```

I am using the above code to get size of the document.

If I upload a document to Google, I am getting the size.
If I create a document/spreadsheet/drawing/presentation/form, I am getting zero as size.

I need solution for the below questions.
1. How to get proper file size of the created Google documents
2. How to differentiate spreadsheet and form.? Both I am getting entry.getType() as spreadsheet.

Please any one help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Google Documents do not use any storage quota on the user's account therefore the reported size will always be zero

2) The Documents List API will will include the element `<docs:hasForm value='true'/>` in the xml response when requesting a form, however, that value is not exposed by the Java client library. You should update to the newer [Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive) and then check the MIME type of the item, which will be `application/vnd.google-apps.form` for a form and `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet` for a spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you please give me java code to differentiate form and spreadsheet?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get shows how to retrieve file metadata and then you have to check the value from `file.getMimeType()`